# Can I move my bathroom sink's drain pipe about 6 inches to the right?

Tags: pipe, drain, pvc

I found the vanity I wanted for my bathroom, but it doesn't fit due to the position of the drain pipe.  It needs to move about 6 inces to the right.  I assume there is some sort of adapter or something that can be used for this, but I know approximately nothing at all about plumbing.  Can this easily be done by the naive DIY'er?  How would I go about determining what size PVC pipe I will need, etc?

Comment: Do you mean the drain where it comes through the wall/floor or where the drain pipe ends within the cabinet?  Can you share some pics?

Comment: It's the drain pipe that comes out of the bottom of the sink and goes into the wall behind the cabinet.  I suppose it would be helpful to have that section of wall tore away and snap a photo, so I will see if I can get that later tonight or tomorrow if necessary.

Comment: The home center will have lots of parts to make this happen. Take a picture and show the plumbing associate what you want to do. A lot will depend on what type of drain material you have.

Moving the drain line is realtively easy, but it does require that you follow some basic rules to make sure it is done correctly. You need to have a proper trap and it must not leak. You also might need some special tools. Post a photo so we can see what you need to do.

Comment: So if you put the vanity in the position you want, would the hole in the wall still be behind the vanity and accessible?

Comment: @ScottBruns Your comment should be posted as an answer. ;)

Comment: My right, or your right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes... Maybe... It depends...

The pipe can defiantly be relocated, the question is how difficult will it be.  It may be as simple as opening the wall, cutting out the old plumbing, adding a few fittings, and closing the wall back up.  Or you might find there is framing in the way, or some other complications.

It's nearly impossible to accurately answer your question, without being able to see what you are dealing with.  The best anybody can do without seeing it, is say yes it can probably most likely maybe be moved.

If you're not sure what to do, or don't feel comfortable doing the work yourself. Remember, your friendly neighborhood plumber is just a phone call away.

Comment: To that end, anything CAN be done.. it's a matter of time/money, and which is directly related to how much you're tearing down and rebuilding. Often the time/money makes the project not worthwhile, such as if you have to reframe an entire exterior wall and move a window, just to move a drain line 6" to the right.. but if you REALLY want to move that line...

Comment: We tore a section of the wall out and discovered that, like you proposed, there is a stud in the way that will greatly affect this effort.  I decided to scrap this and just continue my search for a new vanity.